# TLS 1.2 downgrade to TLS 1.0

Tags: ssl, curl, tls1.2

I've 2 windows server 2012 R2 with all updates.

this server are behind a firewall with IPSEC connection. So we need to connect to a remote API service and we have some strange situation.

1st server connection ok.
via command line with curl command I star connection and with shark I can see the Hello message with protocol TLSv1.2 and connection works fine.

2nd server connection ko.
via command line with curl command I star connection and with shark I can see the Hello message with protocol SSL.

I try to use .net app and the situation still be the same, 1st ok, 2nd KO. if I try to connect to paypal in TLSv1.2 it work fine. I try with other Win Server 2012/2016 but not works.